# "Cannot assign to Service because it is not a variable" using Angular 4 Testbed e2e testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I am using Angular 4 with TestBed, as per the documents here: https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests

I have a simple Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SimpleService {
  getValue() { return 'Hi'; }
}
```

And a test, which instantiates this Service using TestBed:

```
describe('SimpleService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [SimpleService] });
  });

  it('Should say Hello', () => {
    const testBedService: SimpleService = TestBed.get(SimpleService);
    const actual = testBedService.getValue();
    expect(actual).toBe('Hi');
  });
});
```

However, running this test with `ng e2e` gives me the following error:

```
Cannot assign to 'SimpleService' because it is not a variable
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a unit test, not an end-to-end test. If you run it with `ng test` it should work just fine.